# How to add/insert a row with constant values per group?

Tags: sql, postgresql, presto

How can I insert a row per group member with a constant value? For example, the following table is a result of ranking hospital visits per user, from earliest to latest.

```bash
    name       time                        lifetime_visit_at_hospital
    jack       2022-12-02 03:25:00.000     1
    jack       2022-12-02 03:33:00.000     2
    jack       2022-12-03 01:13:00.000     3
    jack       2022-12-03 01:15:00.000     4
    jack       2022-12-04 00:52:00.000     5
    amanda     2017-01-01 05:03:00.000     1
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:36:00.000     2
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:38:00.000     3
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:39:00.000     4
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:40:00.000     5
    amanda     2020-02-14 10:23:00.000     6
    amanda     2020-03-30 03:13:00.000     7
    amanda     2020-09-25 17:17:00.000     8
    amanda     2020-12-23 19:39:00.000     9
    amanda     2021-05-19 20:19:00.000     10
    sam        2023-01-26 23:13:00.000     1
    sam        2023-02-12 17:35:00.000     2
    sam        2023-02-12 17:37:00.000     3
    sam        2023-02-12 17:40:00.000     4
    sam        2023-02-13 16:10:00.000     5
    sam        2023-02-16 19:37:00.000     6
    sam        2023-02-18 16:26:00.000     7
```

I want to add a row per `name`, with value `0` at column `lifetime_visit_at_hospital`.
It would be also helpful to add a constant `time` in the past such as `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` just so I could manage ordering if the table get scrambled later.

So the desired output would be:

```bash
    name       time                        lifetime_visit_at_hospital
    jack       1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     0           <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ desired addition
    jack       2022-12-02 03:25:00.000     1
    jack       2022-12-02 03:33:00.000     2
    jack       2022-12-03 01:13:00.000     3
    jack       2022-12-03 01:15:00.000     4
    jack       2022-12-04 00:52:00.000     5
    amanda     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     0           <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ desired addition
    amanda     2017-01-01 05:03:00.000     1
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:36:00.000     2
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:38:00.000     3
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:39:00.000     4
    amanda     2020-02-13 00:40:00.000     5
    amanda     2020-02-14 10:23:00.000     6
    amanda     2020-03-30 03:13:00.000     7
    amanda     2020-09-25 17:17:00.000     8
    amanda     2020-12-23 19:39:00.000     9
    amanda     2021-05-19 20:19:00.000     10
    sam        1900-01-01 00:00:00.000     0           <~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ desired addition
    sam        2023-01-26 23:13:00.000     1
    sam        2023-02-12 17:35:00.000     2
    sam        2023-02-12 17:37:00.000     3
    sam        2023-02-12 17:40:00.000     4
    sam        2023-02-13 16:10:00.000     5
    sam        2023-02-16 19:37:00.000     6
    sam        2023-02-18 16:26:00.000     7
```

I don't even have a clue how to approach this. I need to run this query on AWS so looking for a `prestodb` solution, but maybe there is a canonical way to do it with postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "insert" you mean add a row per group into query results, then you can use simple `union`:

```sql
-- SAMPLE DATA
WITH dataset(name, time, lifetime_visit_at_hospital) AS (
    values ('jack', '2022-12-02 03:25:00.000', 1),
    ('jack', '2022-12-02 03:33:00.000', 2),
    ('jack', '2022-12-03 01:13:00.000', 3),
    ('jack', '2022-12-03 01:15:00.000', 4),
    ('jack', '2022-12-04 00:52:00.000', 5),
    ('amanda', '2017-01-01 05:03:00.000', 1),
    ('amanda', '2020-02-13 00:36:00.000', 2),
    ('sam', '2023-01-26 23:13:00.000', 1),
    ('sam', '2023-02-12 17:35:00.000', 2)
)

-- QUERY
select *
from
dataset
union select name, '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000', 0
from dataset
group by name
order by name, lifetime_visit_at_hospital;
```

Output:

| name | time | lifetime_visit_at_hospital |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amanda | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| amanda | 2017-01-01 05:03:00.000 | 1 |
| amanda | 2020-02-13 00:36:00.000 | 2 |
| jack | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| jack | 2022-12-02 03:25:00.000 | 1 |
| jack | 2022-12-02 03:33:00.000 | 2 |
| jack | 2022-12-03 01:13:00.000 | 3 |
| jack | 2022-12-03 01:15:00.000 | 4 |
| jack | 2022-12-04 00:52:00.000 | 5 |
| sam | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| sam | 2023-01-26 23:13:00.000 | 1 |
| sam | 2023-02-12 17:35:00.000 | 2 |

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `CROSS JOIN` between your distinct names and the corresponding time/lifetime default values.

```
INSERT INTO tab
SELECT *
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tab) names
CROSS JOIN (VALUES('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'::TIMESTAMP, 0)) times;
```

The output would result into the addition of your needed 3 records (one per distinct name).

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k1UTCePUW5voUCqyi2EBi/0).